# Connected component of identity and normal subgroups

Tags: lie-groups, connectedness, normal-subgroups, path-connected

This is a question with a proof needed in case of a positive answer.

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $H$ a path-connected normal subgroup of $G$, so that the identity in $G$ is also in $H$. Is $H$ the connected component of identity in $G$? If so, what would be a proof? If not, what other conditions on G, H or their factor group are needed to make the answer into a “yes”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $G=GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and let $H=\left\{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\right\}$. Then $H$ is a path-connected normal subgroup of $G$, but the connected component of identity in $G$ is $G$ itself.

Comment: Good answer. In this case, H is discrete. But what if G/H is discrete?

Comment: The assertion $G/H$ is discrete is equivalent to the assertion that $H$ is the connected component of the identity in $G$ (assuming, that is, that $H$ is conneted).

Comment: Do you know of a proof for that?

Comment: Let $G_e$ be the connected component of the identity in $G$. Since $H$ is connected and $e\in H$, $H\subset G_e$. Since $G/H$ is discrete, then so is $G_e/H$. On the other hand, since $H$ is connected, $G_e/H$ is connected if and only if $G_e$ is connected. But $G_e$ *is* connected. Since $G_e/H$ is both connected and discrete, it consists of a single element. Therefore, $G_e=H$.